# Dynamic path problems

Tags: html, dynamic, path

I have a website.

- In the test environment, the URL path = www.SomePath.com/
- In the live environment, the URL path = www.SomePath.com/App/

This affects all script/html/manifest files that look for the main directory, example:

```
<img src="/Images/pic.jpg">
```

What I want:

- Test environment: www.SomePath.com/Images/pic.jpg
- Live environment: www.SomePath.com/App/Images/pic.jpg

What I get:

- Test environment: www.SomePath.com/Images/pic.jpg
- Live environment: www.SomePath.com/Images/pic.jpg **(Error - file path incorrect)**

Comment: I think you need to make some correction in your question. Under `What I want` and `What I get`, are both the points `Test Environment` ?

Comment: I saw, updated it. Thank you

Comment: You can't use relative path?

Comment: I do, but the relative path ends up as an error

Comment: Your site architecture should be the same in test and live so that you can use relative links like you show in your example.

Comment: I agree, but in this case, I am forced to use two separate architectures... Unless if I can somehow change my test architecture to somehow mimic the live.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<img src="Images/pic.jpg">` OR `<img src="./Images/pic.jpg">` instead of <strike>`<img src="/Images/pic.jpg">`</strike>.

When you start a URL with `/`, you specify that the path is to be considered from `root` which is `www.SomePath.com` in both the cases.